# Passing checkbox array from a Form to PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

Thank you for looking at my question.

I am trying to do this:
Use a form with checkboxes: user clicks on several checkboxes (for ONE question).
Then hits "submit"
Then a PHP page takes the form elements and puts them into variables. I can do this with other data, but not sure how to do it with checkboxes (since it is an array).

Could you help me?

```
$Q1 = $_POST['Hood'];  // This one is the array. Let's say it's an array that holds 3 words (red, white, blue). I'm fine if they all get stored in $Q1, I just don't know how to loop through the array (in $POST['Hood']) to get all 3 words in that one variable ($Q1)

$Q2 = $_POST['Handle'];
$Q3 = $_POST['Lever'];
```

So I think I need to figure out how to loop through $_POST['Hood'] in order to get each array element out of it. Please help :)

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your form input must look like and the processing part in PHP. Note the input name has an array initialization:

```
echo '<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="Hood[]" value="some value"> some value<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hood[]" value="some other value"> some other value<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Hood[]" value="1"> a number<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['Hood'])) {

    foreach($_POST['Hood'] as $key=>$value) {

        echo $value;

    }

}
```

Comment: Great, I am going to try it now!